# Laravel 5.2 - Will not recognise SimpleSMS new class provider / alias

Tags: php, laravel, sms, laravel-5

I'm trying to install https://github.com/laggards/simple-sms to my laravel 5.2 project

Within require of my composer.json I have:

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
"laggards/simple-sms": "~2"
```

In config/app.php under providers I have:

```
Laggards\SMS\SMSServiceProvider::class
```

Under aliases I have:

```
'SMS' => Laggards\SMS\Facades\SMS::class
```

At the top of my controller I have:

```
use SMS;
```

Within the controller:

```
SMS::send('This is my message', [], function($sms) {
            $sms->to('+44123456789');
        });
```

Error received:

```
Class 'SMS' not found
```

I have run the following to no success:

```
composer update
composer dump-autoload -o
composer dump-autoload
```

I would appreciate any help on this :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this
Add `Laggards\SMS\SMSServiceProvider::class` in your `config/app.php` configuration file within the `providers array.`

Then Add `'SMS' => Laggards\SMS\Facades\SMS::class` in your `config/app.php` configuration file within the `aliases array.`

After this run this command- `composer dump-autoload`

I followed this documentation and its working for me.
https://github.com/laggards/simple-sms

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be that the documentation is wrong if you use the `~2` version the namespace is actually `SimpleSoftwareIO` instead of `Laggards`. So either use the `dev-master` version so it is `Laggards` or change the namespace to `SimpleSoftwareIO`. I'm not familiar with the package so not sure what the differences are.

You can see the correct documentation for `~2` version [here](https://github.com/laggards/simple-sms/tree/2.0.0).

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your help. 

I have left at version ~2 in my composer.json, and have tried in my config/app.php

SimpleSoftwareIO\SMS\SMSServiceProvider::class
'SMS' => SimpleSoftwareIO\SMS\Facades\SMS::class

I have then run composer dump-autoload -o

However I still get the same problem I'm afraid

Any further advice?

Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Do you have the directory `vendor/laggards/simple-sms/`?

Comment: Going deeper `vendor/laggards/simple-sms/SimpleSoftwareIO/SMS/SMSServiceProvider.php` do you have that with the namespace being `SimpleSoftwareIO\SMS;`?

Comment: Yes - top of that file is:
<?php namespace SimpleSoftwareIO\SMS;

Comment: Can you check `vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php` do you have the line `'SimpleSoftwareIO\\SMS\\' => array($vendorDir . '/laggards/simple-sms/src')`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101044/discussion-between-liam-webster-and-mark-davidson).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
use \SMS;
```

or

```
use Laggards\SMS\Facades\SMS;
```